# Advantages of $e^-e^-$ or $e^+e^+$ collisions over $e^+e^-$ collisions?

Tags: particle-physics, collision, leptons

Is there any (interesting) HEP process whose study would take advantage from $e^-e^-$ or $e^+e^+$ collisions with respect to $e^+e^-$ collisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $e^-e^-$ or $e^+e^+$ means that the final states need to be charged and have lepton number of two. This produces a different set of potential final products then $e^-e^+$. One such example would be $e^- e ^- \rightarrow \mu ^-\mu^- $. While this may be an interesting collision for some new theory, such interactions can only produce a very particular type of final state. Furthermore, it is difficult to use this type of collider for QCD interactions. While there is a probability for the electrons to collide and produce mesons and baryons it is strongly suppressed due to lepton number conservation.

This situation can be contrasted with colliding protons together. Protons at the LHC are mostly made up of gluons. Thus when you are colliding protons at $ 14 \mbox{ TeV}$ you are essentially colliding gluons. Gluons, unlike fermions, don't obey any conservation law such as baryon number of lepton number which will limit your potential final states.